# Can't Display Image Using MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, image, mean-stack

I am using the MEAN stack and trying to display an image stored in my Mongo database.  I believe that the image is correctly stored and being correctly passed to the browser as when I use Web Console and look at the response to my Post the Response Body displays the image.

I have a table and when a row is clicked it makes a call to my controller:

```
$scope.detailRequest = function(index){
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
    $scope.selected = this.contact;
        $http.post('/DetailRequest', $scope.selected).success(function(response){
            $scope.detailResponse = response;
        });
};
```

In Node I query Mongo and return the image:

```
router.post('/DetailRequest', function(request, response) {
  reports
    .findOne({_id : request.body._id})
    .select('img')
    .exec(function (err, research) {
       response.contentType(research.img.contentType);
       response.send(research);   
    });
});
```

I am using the `ng-src` for image display.  As I mention at the top of the page I can see the image correctly in the Response Body of the Web Console.  Thus, I am confident I am getting the image back to the browser.

```
<img ng-src="{{detailResponse}}">
```

The image just won't display

Comment: ng-src is used to set the url that returns the image instead of set to an image response.

Comment: Are you just storing the URL to the image,  the image data encoded as base64 or as `BinData` ?

Comment: I'm storing the encoded image as BinData.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your wires crossed a bit here.

ng-src will set the Img src property to a URL.  The browser will then load the src URL with a GET request.

```
<img ng-src="{{someUrlRequestedWithGet}}">
```

So your Express route should be a [GET](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req):

```
router.get('/DetailRequest/:id', function(request, response) {
   reports
        .findOne({_id : request.params._id})
        .select('img')
        .exec( function  (err, research) {
          response.contentType(research.img.contentType);
          response.send(research);   
   });
```

Note: instead of putting the id in the body, you put it in the URL.

Hint: Whatever URL is in ng-src should display when pasted into a browser bar.

There's also a way to get the image data from a POST (although that's [not really the best use of POST](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post)).  But you'll have to get a bit more tactical and use a [data-uri](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Comment: Michael - I left a key piece of information.  I am storing the image in Mongo as encoded BinData.  (Note: the images are small 6KB each)  Therefore, it is not the URL to the image that I am returning it is the binary representation of the image.

Comment: @user1952069, Ok, I got that, check my answer again.  If you paste the Express route into a browser bar, and it shows an image, then ng-src will work.  For that to work, it needs to be a GET request.  If you're using a GET, and it's not working in the browser, then you may have a bug in your encoding (you said you saw the image in network traffic, so you're probably ok here).

Answer (score 0):

So something on these lines in Angular should work:
JavaScript:
`$scope.imageData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64' + Base64LongLongString;`

Template:
`<img ng-src="imageData" />`

Let's see why it should work.
`<img src="">` expects a uri, so that wouldn't work in your case if we feed uri in this attribute. `ng-src` with uri would have same problem.

An image with binary data embedded has the src attribute as:
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/Base64LongLongString">`
More about this representation at http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/33713/using-binary-image-data-to-display-an-image-in-html